# Java NullPointerException when adding to ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

My code is throwing a NullPointerException, even though the object seems to properly exist.

```
public class IrregularPolygon {

    private ArrayList<Point2D.Double> myPolygon;

    public void add(Point2D.Double aPoint) {
        System.out.println(aPoint); // Outputs Point2D.Double[20.0, 10.0]
        myPolygon.add(aPoint); // NullPointerException gets thrown here
    }
}

// Everything below this line is called by main()

    IrregularPolygon poly = new IrregularPolygon();
    Point2D.Double a = new Point2D.Double(20,10);
    poly.add(a);
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

based on the parts of the code you provided, it looks like you haven't initialized `myPolygon`

Answer (score 20):

```
private ArrayList<Point2D.Double> myPolygon = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
```

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you initialize the List:

```
private List<Point2D.Double> myPolygon = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
```

Also note that it's best to define myPolygon as a List (interface) and not ArrayList (implementation).

Comment: Is this still true? I don't think so, because if you initialise it as an `ArrayList` then you do not need to specify a type on the other side of the argument anymore.

Comment: May I know why? What is the advantage?: "Also note that it's best to define myPolygon as a List (interface) and not ArrayList (implementation)"